# Nestjs with Swagger ( Open API ) on Dummy/Mock data

Tags: nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger, swagger-ui-express

I am working with nestjs and using its swagger implementation.

I want my documentation to work on mock data.
I am using *@nestjs/swagger* and *swagger-ui-express* libraries.

Currently it is working on my database.
I want it to work on mock data.